# Backbone Events in ES6

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

I have been working with Backbone in ES5 form for quite some time and I'm looking to try and build a new project in ES6. I've built this very basic view just to test out my build processes etc.

I can get the view to render as expected in the el. However, I cannot seem to get the event to fire at all. I'm sure that I'm missing something simple but I cannot seem to find what it is.

```js
import $ from "jquery";
import _ from 'underscore';
import Backbone from 'backbone';

class basicView extends Backbone.View {
 constructor(options) {
  super();
  this.options = options;
  this.events = {
   'click #bc': 'clickHandler'
  };
  this.render();
 }

 render() {
  $(this.options.el).html('<a id="bc" href="#">button</a>');
  return this;
 }

 clickHandler() {
  alert("button clicked");
  return false;
 }
};

$(() => {
 new basicView({
  el: '#container'
 });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>es6</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">

  </div>
  <script src="ui/js/production/home.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in your constructor, you define `events` **after** invoking Backbone.View's code that does things like parsing event hash and binding events.

```
constructor(options) {
    super();
    // ^---- don't have an event hash when this code executes.
    this.events = { // this is now useless
        'click #bc': 'clickHandler'
    };
```

`super(options)` and passing events hash in `options` might work.
Simple and elegant solution: use `Backbone.View.extend()` instead of `class`. You are not gaining anything but disadvantages by using `class` with backbone. You can still use all other ES6 features in your project.

Comment: Thanks TJ, i'll give that a try. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

As TJ recommended, this solution works well. Thanks again. We are trying to decide whether we should make Backbone work on ES6 as we currently use it on ES5 vs re-tooling completely on to Vue.js so this is a good first step on our journey.

```js
import $ from "jquery";
import _ from 'underscore';
import Backbone from 'backbone';

class basicView extends Backbone.View {
 constructor(options) {
  super(options);
  this.options = options;
  this.render();
 }

 render() {
  $(this.options.el).append('<a id="bc" href="#">button</a>');
  return this;
 }

 clickHandler() {
  console.log("click");
  return false;
 }
};

new basicView({
 el: '#container',
 events: {
  'click a#bc': 'clickHandler'
 }
});
```